# A repunit is a number that contains only “ones” (for example $111$, $1111111$,….). Prove that one can find a repunit divisible by $1973$

Tags: proof-writing, pigeonhole-principle, repunit-numbers

It is a pigeonhole problem.

I have already known that there are $1972$ remainders in total and the two numbers which have the same remainder can be subtracted and the difference between the two numbers is divisible by $1973$.

BUT the difference is not a repunit number, it will be like $1111111...0000000$

Can someone help me out?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Well, $\gcd(1973, 10^k)=1$.

Comment: Cf. [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3358966/can-673-multiplied-give-a-number-written-with-only-ones)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dividing that difference by $10^n$ for a suitable value of $n$ will not change whether it's divisible by $1973$. And thus you are done.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative solution, $1973$ is prime, so $10^{1972}\equiv1\mod1973$ by Fermat's little theorem,

so $1973$ divides $
\dfrac{10^{1972}-1}9.$

Comment: In fact, $1973$ divides $
\dfrac{10^{986}-1}9.$